# Handling many-layer queries using GeoExt/Geoserver/OpenLayers?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geoext, search

Am developing an application using GeoExt/OpenLayers and Geoeserver and am using more than ten (10) layers.  I wanted to add a querying functionality on my application.  I have done for one layer and is working really fine.

**Code**

```
var secStore = Ext.create('GeoExt.data.FeatureStore', {
        layer: secschools,
        fields: [
            {name: 'Name_of_Sc', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Girls_Boys', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'School_Spo', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Day_or_Boa', type: 'string'},
        ]
    });
    secStore.load();
    var sm = Ext.create('GeoExt.selection.FeatureModel', {
            autoPanMapOnSelection: true,
            mode: 'MULTI'
    });
var secGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel',{
        store: secStore,
        autoScroll:true,
        layout:'fit',
        columns: [{header: "Name", flex:0.4, dataIndex: "Name_of_Sc"},
                {header: "Sponsor", flex:0.2, dataIndex: "School_Spo"},
                {header: "Girls/Boys", flex:0.2, dataIndex: "Girls_Boys"},
                {header: "Day/Boarding", flex:0.2, dataIndex: "Day_or_Boa"},
                ],
        tbar:[{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                width:100,
                margin: 2,
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                listeners: {
                    keyup: function() {
                        var store = this.up('grid').store;
                        store.clearFilter();
                        if (this.value) {
                            store.filter({
                                property     : 'Name_of_Sc',
                                value         : this.value,
                                anyMatch      : true,
                                caseSensitive : false
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    buffer: 500
                }
            }
        ],
        selModel:sm,
        stripeRows: true,
        columnLines:true,
        selType: 'featuremodel',
    });
```

The secschools is a WFS layer added on my map.As you can see the grid displays the records form the secschools layer and can be filtered using the textfield.
The issue is, I will have to repeat this code as many times as the layers I want queried.

How can I handle such a querying functionality (to search e.g. 10 layers) in my app without doing as above?

Answer (score 1):

You could use OpenLayers.Format.WFSDescribeFeatureType to make a DescribeFeatureType-Request and use the response to reconfigure your store and fill your grid.

Just have a look at the following GeoExt-Workshop (especially the "Bonus Task"-Section):
http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/geoext/wfs/grid.html

I won't post all the code from this workshop here as it's just too much an can be found on the workshop-website, but the following code-snippet will give you an idea how to get the information which fields have to be created for each layer :

```
var rawAttributeData;
var read = OpenLayers.Format.WFSDescribeFeatureType.prototype.read;
OpenLayers.Format.WFSDescribeFeatureType.prototype.read = function() {
    rawAttributeData = read.apply(this, arguments);
    return rawAttributeData;
};
```

If your store will be reconfigured for each active layer you can setup a more generic filter function in a next step.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for this.I had looked at the example but what I can't understand is how to do this for each layer.I have eight layers that I want do display their attributes once selected.

Comment: This is already done in the example. see this section: --- "When a layer is selected in the tree by clicking on its name, we want to issue a DescribeFeatureType request. This is done by appending the following code:" ---  The selectionchange-event of the tree-selectionmodel is used to reconfigure the store and the grid.